# How to set two data sources in java LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?

Tags: javabeans, multiple-databases, xmlbeans, hibernate-entitymanager

In xml format, you can define some code as below to set two data sources without problems:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zangland.routing.RoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="com.zangland.routing.DbType">
            <entry key="MASTER" value-ref="dataSourceMaster"/>
            <entry key="REPLICA" value-ref="dataSourceReplica"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="dataSourceMaster"/>
</bean>
```

if I try to convert it in java like this, it will make error

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "masterEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.zangland"});
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("master");

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory masterEntityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(masterEntityManager);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public RoutingDataSource dataSource() {
        RoutingDataSource dataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        dataSourceMap.put(DbType.MASTER, dataSourceMaster());
        dataSourceMap.put(DbType.REPLICA, dataSourceReplica());
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceMaster());
        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return dataSource;
    }
```

and the error will be here as below:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'masterEntityManager' defined in class path
>   resource [com/zangland/routing/DataSourceConfiguration.class]: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
>   Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path
>   resource [com/zangland/routing/DataSourceConfiguration.class]: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zangland.routing.RoutingDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSourceMaster' defined in class path
>   resource [com/zangland/routing/DataSourceConfiguration.class]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'routingDataSource' defined in file
>   [C:\workspace\routing-data-springboot\target\classes\com\zangland\routing\RoutingDataSource.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'targetDataSources' is
>   required

Comment: Look here: `is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'targetDataSources' is required`

Comment: 'targetDataSources' is in AbstractRoutingDataSource, RoutingDataSource jsut extents that class. How can I do?

Comment: Show your RoutingDataSource class.

Comment: public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DbContextHolder.getDbType();
    }
}